# File Download Java

Tags: java, download, corrupt

I have written the following code to download files from the file server. While downloading, I do not get any runtime error but it always says file corrupt.

I am retrieving the file details from the database:
Reading the contents in byte form to the output stream.

This code works fine for all txt files however for all other types, the size of file increases and when i try to open, it says file is corrupted

```
public void download(Long requestId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    byte[] out;
    ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    String fileServerPath = parametersService.getParameters(AppConstants.FILE_SERVER_PATH);
    FileVO fileVO = dao.getFileDetails(requestId);
    String filePath = fileServerPath + fileVO.getFilePath() + fileVO.getFileName();
    try {
        if (FileUtil.isFileExist(filePath)) {
            File apFile = new File(filePath);
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(apFile));
            String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(apFile.getName());
            if(mimeType==null){
                //if mimetype is not detectable, will take default
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            /* Start: Set the MIME type, file name and meta detail in response */
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", apFile.getName()));
            response.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(apFile.length()));
            /* End: Set the MIME type, file name and meta detail in response */
            /* START: Read byte by byte and write to servlet output stream */
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            int read;
            final byte[] data = new byte[1 * 1024];
            int i=0;
            while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, read);
                i++;
                slf4jLogger.debug("Writing data "+ i );
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            in.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Exception
    }
}
```

My front end is in Angular 1.5. I am using file-saver lib to achieve.
Following is the code

```
function download() {
        var url = apiHelper.getRootUrl() + '/request/' + '/download/' + vm.request.requestId;
        $http.post(url, {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).success(
                function (response, status, headers) {
                    var type = headers()['content-type'];
                    var disposition = headers()['content-disposition'];
                    if (disposition) {
                        var match = disposition.match(/.*filename=\"?([^;\"]+)\"?.*/);
                        if (match[1])
                            var defaultFileName = match[1];
                    }
                    defaultFileName = defaultFileName.replace(/[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '_');
                    var blob = new Blob([response], {type: type});
                    saveAs(blob, defaultFileName);
                });
    }
```

Comment: this code looks correct.  did you implement the client side as well?  maybe there's a bug on the other end.

Comment: you are swallowing any potential IOException which is generally a bad idea.  there could be an exception you are ignoring.

Comment: can you compare the files on either end?  is there actually file corruption?

Comment: This code works fine for all txt files however for all other types, the size of file increases and when i try to open, it says file is corrupted.

Comment: can you please upload both the data in the database and the resulting download?

Comment: You should not set the Content-length header. `HttpServletResponse` will do that for you. Your comment 'read byte by byte' is not correct: you are reading up to 1024 bytes at a time (and you should probably use a larger buffer, like 8k).

Comment: what you are describing sounds like a situation where you are treating binary data like text.  this can cause thinks like the newline character to have a carriage return added (which will corrupt the binary data).  however, nothing in the code you have shown should cause that problem.  i think your issue is elsewhere.  is there other code manipulating the files (on either end) before you open it?

Comment: to clarify @EJP's comment, you should be calling setContentLength() on the response, not setting the content length header.

Comment: @jtahlborn To clarify my response, he shouldn't do that either. Java will set it automatically.

Comment: @EJP - if you know the content length, it is better to set it so that the response can be streamed directly.